# How to round up percentage in 0 decimal in R

Tags: r, format, decimal, rounding, percentage

Looking for a easy method like EXCEL "Increase decimal","Decrease decimal"

```
# Example number
d <- c(0.6199548,0.8884106,0.9030066)

# Expected result :
[1]62% 89% 90%

# library scales result cannot adjust to 0 decimal
percent(d)
[1] "62.0%" "88.8%" "90.3%"

# Cannot handle sprinf() function well as weird result generated like below: 
sprintf("%.1f %%", d)
[1] "0.6 %" "0.9 %" "0.9 %"
```

Do we have simple package to adjust the decimal percentage as easy as EXCEL in R?

Comment: @Marius - or even `sprintf("%.0f%%", d * 100)`  - if you want 0 decimals you have to ask for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `round` and `paste`:

```
d <- c(0.6199548,0.8884106,0.9030066)
paste0(round(d*100), "%")

[1] "62%" "89%" "90%"
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest looking at the documentation of `?percent` before you decide what it can and can't do.

```
# library scales result cannot adjust to 0 decimal
## OR CAN IT
percent(d, 1)
[1] "62%" "89%" "90%"
```

From the help page `?percent`:

```
percent(x, accuracy = NULL, scale = 100, prefix = "",
  suffix = "%", big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ".", trim = TRUE,
  ...)
# ...
# accuracy  Number to round to, NULL for automatic guess.
```

Comment: Yes , but i have got this error before i posted the question : `percent(d, 1) Error in percent(d, 1) : unused argument (1)`

Comment: Maybe you are using a `percent` function from another package? Or maybe you have an old version of `scales`? Looking at the package news it looks like the `accuracy` argument was introduced in version 1.0. As I show in the answer, works just fine for me.

Comment: thank you Gregor , i think i should check the version of scales